# Serialize class based on one interface it implements with Jackson or Gson

Tags: serialization, jackson, deserialization, gson

I have the following:

An interface I1 extends Ia, Ib, Ic

An interface I2.

A class C implements I1, I2. And this class has its own setters and getters as well.

C cInstance = new C():

```
//Jackson
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.writeValue(new File("somefile.json"), cInstance);

//Gson
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(cInstance);
```

The output will be cInstance serialized according to the properties of C and what it inherited.
However, I like the properties are being serialized to be according to the setters/getters in I1 (only the cInstance properties represented in the I1 interface).

How can I do this with Jackson knowing that I have too many classes with the same problem and I can't modify the class definition or add annotations.

And the same issue applies to Deserialization (Deserializing according to an interface)

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you can always attach "mix-in annotations" even without adding annotations directly (see [wiki page](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonMixInAnnotations)). With this, annotation to use would be:

```
@JsonSerialize(as=MyInterface.class)
```

but if you do not want to use mix-ins, you can force specific type to use with

```
objectMapper.typedWriter(MyInterface.class).writeValue(....)
```

Comment: It should be @JsonSerialize(as = MyInterface.class) but unfortunately that is not working for me in jackson 2.1.1 . The using attribute is for specifying a JsonSerializer implementation.

Comment: Yes you are correct -- edited with correct value. I thought this should actually work (there are issues in trying to force structured values like `List`s), but root values are problematic, compared to property values (which do work correctly).

Comment: Nowadays second option looks like `objectMapper.writerFor(UserResponse.class).writeValue...` (Jackson 2.9.6)

Answer (score 0):

Jackson's `VisibilityChecker` provides an easy way for filtering certain properties, especially because it allows you to test for visibility (equals "will be serialized or not") for each method/field individually.

At least this helps for the serialization phase.

Here is what I did (using Jackson version 1.9.11):

```
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.introspect.AnnotatedMethod;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.introspect.VisibilityChecker;

public static class InterfaceVisibilityChecker extends VisibilityChecker.Std {

    private final Set<Method> visibleMethods;

    public InterfaceVisibilityChecker(Class<?>... clazzes) {
        super(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.PUBLIC_ONLY);

        this.visibleMethods = new HashSet<>();
        for (Class<?> clz : clazzes) {
            this.visibleMethods.addAll(Arrays.asList(clz.getMethods()));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isGetterVisible(Method m) {
        return super.isGetterVisible(m) && isVisible(m);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isGetterVisible(AnnotatedMethod m) {
        return isGetterVisible(m.getAnnotated());
    }

    private boolean isVisible(Method m) {
        for (Method visiMthd : visibleMethods) {
            if (isOverwriteMethod(m, visiMthd)) return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private boolean isOverwriteMethod(Method subMethod, Method superMethod) {

        // names must be equal
        if (! subMethod.getName().equals(superMethod.getName())) return false;

        // return types must be assignable
        if (! superMethod.getReturnType().isAssignableFrom(subMethod.getReturnType())) return false;

        // parameters must be equal
        if (! Arrays.equals(subMethod.getParameterTypes(), superMethod.getGenericParameterTypes())) return false;

        // classes must be assignable
        return superMethod.getDeclaringClass().isAssignableFrom(subMethod.getDeclaringClass());
    }
}
```

The main idea is to use the standard `VisibilityChecker` and extend it by a check whether the method is declared in one of the given interfaces.

The checker is applied to an ObjectMapper instance using the following snippet:

```
ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
om.setVisibilityChecker(new InterfaceVisibilityChecker(
     I1.class, 
     I2.class, 
     Ia.class, 
     Ib.class, 
     Ic.class
```

));

Some comments on the solution above:

1. The checker is not complete, methods like `isIsGetterVisible` or `isFieldVisible` can be handled in a similar manner if needed.
2. `isOverwriteMethod` is not optimized at all, it's checks could be cached.