# Jackson serialize only interface methods

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I have one object *A* with some methods *ma*, *mb*, *mc* and this object implements an interface *B* with only *ma* and *mb*.

When I serialize *B* I expect only *ma* and *mb* as a json response but I get as well *mc*.

I'd like to automatize this behaviour so that all the classes I serialize get serialized based on the interface and not on the implementation.

How should I do that?

Example:

```
public interface Interf {
    public boolean isNo();

    public int getCountI();

    public long getLonGuis();
}
```

Implementation:

```
public class Impl implements Interf {

    private final String patata = "Patata";

    private final Integer count = 231321;

    private final Boolean yes = true;

    private final boolean no = false;

    private final int countI = 23;

    private final long lonGuis = 4324523423423423432L;

    public String getPatata() {
        return patata;
    }


    public Integer getCount() {
        return count;
    }


    public Boolean getYes() {
        return yes;
    }


    public boolean isNo() {
        return no;
    }


    public int getCountI() {
        return countI;
    }

    public long getLonGuis() {
        return lonGuis;
    }

}
```

Serialization:

```
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    Interf interf = new Impl();
    String str = mapper.writeValueAsString(interf);

    System.out.println(str);
```

Response:

```
 {
    "patata": "Patata",
    "count": 231321,
    "yes": true,
    "no": false,
    "countI": 23,
    "lonGuis": 4324523423423423500
}
```

Expected response:

```
 {
    "no": false,
    "countI": 23,
    "lonGuis": 4324523423423423500
 }
```

Comment: similar issue: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8922309/serialize-class-based-on-one-interface-it-implements-with-jackson-or-gson][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8922309/serialize-class-based-on-one-interface-it-implements-with-jackson-or-gson

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Just annotate your interface such that Jackson constructs data fields according to the interface's class and not the underlying object's class.

```
@JsonSerialize(as=Interf.class)
public interface Interf {
  public boolean isNo();
  public int getCountI();
  public long getLonGuis();
}
```

Comment: What if I have multiple interfaces for my impl class and I want to serialize the object as per the getters defined in interfaces.

Comment: I want to return different interfaces from different services.

Comment: @varun you should probably setup different endpoints to return different data structures. That is, getFoo() returns the Foo interface and getBar() returns the Bar interface, where Foo and Bar have the same underlying impl class.

Comment: That doesnt work, Jackson always serializes the underlying implementation no matter what the interfaces.

Comment: @varun I can get Jackson to return a structure that matches one interface, but I was not correct about returning two different data structures per two interfaces. My answer to annotate the _interface_ with `@JsonSerialize` happens to work because Jackson looks through the list of interfaces for applicable annotations. It works for the OP, but was not doing what I thought it did.

Comment: I created a gist (https://gist.github.com/bseib/095a6809c9e9be34d7b9) that demos the multiple interface issue more clearly. This probably deserves to be posted as a separate SO question since it involves multiple interfaces, which differs from this question.

Comment: Thanks broc, I will post this as a separate question.

Comment: @varun, can you share the SO link here after you post the new question?

Comment: @broc.seib what should work is that you make a common interface that extends both `Description` and `Dimensions`, but yeah that is a workaround for your problem. :(

Comment: This is a great way to deploy information hiding when @JsonView is not a suitable candidate.

Comment: @froginvasion I have a similar problem and I tried the solution with the common interface but it didn't work. Can you elaborate a little more please in case I am missing something.

Answer (score 11):

You have two options:

1) put `@JsonSerialize` annotation on your interface (see [@broc.seib answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31030804/355438))

2) or use specific writer for the serialization (as of Jackson 2.9.6):

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String str = mapper.writerFor(Interf.class).writeValueAsString(interf);
```