# How Spring mvc serials result with jackson and based on annotation of the return value?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jackson

There is a Spring MVC REST call:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/new", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public IQuery create(@RequestParam Map<String, Object> propertiesMap){...}
```

As you can see, the result value is an interface with getter method. There is an special implementation:

```
public class QueryImp implements IQuery{..}
```

the actual result of rest method is QueryImp but I want the json result just contains attributes which a getter method exist in interface.

EDIT:

In the other hand, QueryImp is one of the possible output. The system is base 
 on maven module and spring injection, so 3th party modules are allowed to implements there own classes. We are about to not limit contributors.

Comment: possible dup: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18654293/jackson-serialize-only-interface-methods

Comment: Dear @kevin, thanks to your comment. It is an special case and I update the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution is to create a wrapper as follow:

```
public class QueryWrapper implments IQuery{
  @JsonIgnor
  private IQuery ref;

  public QueryWrapper(IQuery ref){
    this.ref = ref;
  }
  // wrap all methods
}
```

And finally wrap all instances:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/new", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public IQuery create(@RequestParam Map<String, Object> propertiesMap){
    IQuery query = null;
    ...
    return new QueryWrapper(query);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So, if I understand properly, you have multiple implementations of `IQuery`, and the serialization needs are determined by the implementation? And for a specific case (`QueryImpl`) you'd like for it to only serialize the interface exposed properties?

If that's a correct statement of your issue, I think what you really should be doing is controlling serialization with `@JsonIgnore` or `@JsonIgnoreProperties` on the implementation class. That way each implementation class determines its own serialization behavior.